# Search all xml files recursively in directory for a specific tag and grep the tag's value

Tags: command-line, find, xml

Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty Tahr.

Suppose I have directory called 'testmag' which may contain 100s of xml files and directories which in turn contain many xml files as well. I don't know names of any xml files but I know one of them contains tag `<dbname>....</dbname>`.

Now how to find the file containing the aforementioned tag and grep the tag's value as output in terminal

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution with `find` that will also output the filenames of files containing a match:

```
find . -name "*.xml" -exec grep '<dbname>' {} \;             \
                     -exec echo -e {}"\n" \;                 \
                     | sed 's/<dbname>\(.*\)<\/dbname>/\1/g'
```

**Explanation**

1. `find . -name "*.xml"` find all xml files recursively from current directory
2. `-exec grep '<dbname>' {} \;` on each file search for pattern `<dbname>`
3. `-exec echo -e {}"\n" \;` echo filename + new line (`-e` option makes echo interpret `\n`)
4. `| sed 's/<dbname>\(.*\)<\/dbname>/\1/g'` pipe output to `sed` to print only the field contained between the `<dbname></dbname>` tags.

NOTE1: you can format output in your `echo -e ...` to have results for each file clearly laid out, e.g. by adding new lines, or lines of underscore, whatever suits your need.

NOTE2: path to each file will be given relatively to `.` (e.g. `./subfolder1/file.xml`). If you want absolute path, go for `find $PWD -name ...`.

Comment: This exactly answers my query, perfect !!! Thanks @Valentin B.

Comment: Well as far as question is concerned, your post answers it, no doubt, but just one query out of curiosity, if you don't mind. With above `find` command if I want to look for only `<dbname>...</dbname>` tag having `<![CDATA[` as it's content's starting string and ignore the rest of the `<dbname>...` matches, how can I achieve it ?

Comment: Hi Vicky, simply add the pattern in your `grep` command, `... -exec grep '<dbname><![CDATA[' {} \; ...`

Comment: This assumes that the `dbname` node's start and end tag are on the same line.

Answer (score 4):

Using a proper XML parser to parse XML:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
for file in **/*.xml; do 
    dbname=$(xmlstarlet sel -t -v '//dbname' "$file")
    [[ -n "$dbname" ]] && printf "%s\t%s\n" "$file" "$dbname"
done
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `find` with `xq`:

```bsh
find testmag -type f -name '*.xml' -exec xq -r '..|(.dbname? // empty)' {} +
```

This would find all regular files with names matching `*.xml` in or below the `testmag` directory.  For batches of these, `xq` would be called to extract the value of every `dbname` node found in those documents.

`xq` is a `jq`-like XML parser that is distributed with `yq` from https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/

---

Would you need the filenames of all XML files that have this node, you could use

```bsh
find testmag -type f -name '*.xml' -exec xq -e '..|(.dbname? // empty)' {} \; -print
```

... although this would be a fair bit slower than just extracting the value of the node as we need to invoke `xq` once for each file.

Comment: Hi, one question, please. `jq`, `yq`, `xq`, these tools has no option for themselves for recursion?

Comment: @αғsнιη You mean to recurse into directories? No, they are parsers. The task of providing the tools with filenames is left to the calling shell.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have directory `XMLS` containing these files:

```
cat XMLS/file1
foo bar <dbname>target</dbname> baz
foo foo

cat XMLS/file2
<name>notarget</name>
```

I would use this command:

```
grep -r '<dbname>' XMLS/ | sed 's/.*<dbname>\(.*\)<\/dbname>.*/\1/'
target
```

Which, as you can see, returns the value inside the `<dbname>` tags. And not the value inside the `<name>` tags.

The `-r` flag for `grep` searches recursively.

`sed` strips the string of everything except the value `target`.

Comment: Can I use `.` for recursive search inside current directory  ?

Comment: @VickyDev Yes, `.` works fine.

Comment: Why is `target` on second line ? Is it required in code ?

Comment: @VickyDev What? No. That is the actual output from the command.

Comment: @maulinglawns You should add `g` at the end of your `sed` instructions otherwise in case of multiple matches from `grep` only the first pattern will be processed.

Comment: This assumes that the `dbname` node's start and end tag are on the same line.